# Powershell find folders, delete files leaving latest 5

Tags: powershell

We use software called Revit, files are saved as such: filename.rvt

Each time a user edits a file, Revit takes it upon itself to save the old file in the format filename.xxxx.rvt (where xxx is a number).

Over time when files are edited hundreds of times, we have many unnecessary files on the file server.

I am writing a script to:

- Locate and folders containing Revit backup files
- Delete all but the most recently modified 5 revit backup files

I have tried two approaches below

```
$searchpath = "e:\"
# Find a unique list of directories that contains a revit backup file (*.*.rvt)
$a = Get-ChildItem -Path $searchpath -Include *.*.rvt -Recurse | Select-object Directory -expandproperty FullName | Get-Unique -AsString

# For each folder that contains a single revit backup file (*.*.rvt)...
# - Sort by modified time
# - Select all except first 5
$a | Get-ChildItem -Include *.*.rvt | Sort-Object LastWriteTime -descending | select-object -skip 5 -property Directory,Name,CreationTime,LastWriteTime | Out-GridView -Title "Old Backups" -PassThru
```

The issue with this approach is that it only "skips" the first 5 files in the entire search result, not 5 in each folder.

Then I went about it using a loop, and this gets nowhere:

```
$searchpath = "e:\"

# Find a unique list of directories that contains a revit backup file (*.*.rvt)
$a = Get-ChildItem -Path $searchpath -Include *.*.rvt -Recurse | Select Directory | Get-Unique -AsString 

# For each folder that contains a single revit backup file (*.*.rvt)...
# - Sort by modified time
# - Select all except first 5
$a | foreach {
 $b += Get-ChildItem -Path $_.Directory.FullName -Include *.*.rvt | Sort-Object LastWriteTime -descending | select-object -skip 5 -property Directory,Name,CreationTime,LastWriteTime
}

$b | Out-GridView -Title "Old Backups" -PassThru
```

Any thoughts on the correct approach and whats going wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The key to do what you seek is to use the `Group-Object` cmdlet.

In your case, the group you want to create is a group containing all items in the same folder. This will give you something like this:

[image: Grouped object]

From there, you can perform actions on each group, such as selecting all the files while skipping the first 5 of each folders and deleting the remaining.

See this simple minimalist example:

```
$Path = 'C:\__TMP\1'
$Items = Get-ChildItem -Path "$path\*.rvt" -Recurse | Group-Object -Property PsparentPath

Foreach ($ItemsGroup in $Items) {
    $SortedFiles = $ItemsGroup.Group | sort LastWriteTime -Descending
    $SortedFiles | Select-Object -Skip 5 | % {Write-host "Deleting $($_.FullName)";  Remove-Item $_.FullName}
}
```

Comment: I think it's smart to give the user a UI - since we are deleting files...

Comment: Foreach ($ItemsGroup in $Items) {
        $SortedFiles = $ItemsGroup.Group | sort LastWriteTime -Descending
        $a += ($SortedFiles | Select-Object -Skip 5 -property Directory,Name,CreationTime,LastWriteTime)
    }

    $a | Out-GridView -Title "Old Backups" -PassThru | Remove-Item -Force

Comment: Gives error: Remove-Item : Cannot find drive. A drive with the name '@{Directory=C' does not exist.

Comment: Resolved:

$a | Out-GridView -Title "Old Backups" -PassThru | ForEach-Object { Remove-Item "$($_.Directory)\$($_.Name)" -WhatIf }

Answer (score 3):

try this:

```
get-childitem -file -recurse | group Directory | where Count -gt 5 | %{
    $_.Group | Sort LastWriteTime -descending | select -skip 5 Directory,Name,CreationTime,LastWriteTime 
} | Out-GridView -Title "Old Backups"
```

If you want delete you can do it (remove what if)

```
gci -file -recurse | group Directory | where Count -gt 5 | %{
$_.Group | Sort LastWriteTime -descending | select -skip 5 | remove-item -WhatIf 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this:

```
$searchpath = "E:\"
$number = 5

$directories = Get-ChildItem -Path $searchpath -Include *.*.rvt -Recurse | Where-Object {$_.PsIsContainer}
foreach ($dir in $directories) 
{
    $files = Get-ChildItem -Path $dir.FullName | Where-Object {-not $_.PsIsContainer}
    if ($files.Count -gt $number) 
{
  $files | Sort-Object CreationTime | Select-Object -First ($files.Count - $number) | Remove-Item -Force
}
}
```

Change the placeholders accordingly. I just gave you the logical approach.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. The first Get-ChildItem is searching folder names not filenames.

Comment: Yes and you need that only. Reason:- U wish to pick the folders where those files are there and not all folders. Then once done ,do the necessary operation within the loop. :)

Comment: I need to search the filename to locate the folder, not the folder name.

Comment: Go Ahead then . Remove the folder condition from the where-object and put your criteria. :)

Answer (score 0):

An alternative solution that doesn't require grouping first and instead processes each directory separately:

```sh
& { Get-Item $path; Get-ChildItem -Directory -Recurse $path } | # get all dirs.
  ForEach-Object {                            # for each dir.
    Get-ChildItem -File $_.FullName/*.*.rvt | # get backup files in dir.
      Sort-Object -Descending LastWriteTime | # sort by last-write time, newest first
        Select-Object -Skip 5 |               # skip the 5 newest
          Remove-Item -Force -WhatIf          # delete
  }
```

<sup>Note: The [`-WhatIf` common parameter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_commonparameters#whatif) in the command above *previews* the operation. Remove `-WhatIf`  once you're sure the operation will do what you want.</sup>